# oEmbed cannot change parameter visual to false

Tags: soundcloud

When I query for SoundCloud oEmbed it return parameter `visual=true` by default.

After adding `visual=false` into the end of query, it still returning with full embed player instead of small one.

`https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?visual=true&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2FSOMETRACK&show_artwork=true&color=%231976d2&show_comments=false&visual=false`
Should SoundCloud send `visual=true` by default?

PS. I noticed that this problem occur since 2014

Answer (score 0):

Are you a pro soundcloud member or pro unlimited? It seems they are required to access the mini embedded widget.

https://soundcloud.com/pro

Comment: No, just classic embed

Comment: This is what I trying yo achive [link](https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F126563320&show_artwork=true&color=%231976d2&show_comments=false&visual=false) but I cannot getting there because of `visual=true` in the front that SoundCloud return to me